# How to plot a matlab function for different parameters using hold on command

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I have a matlab function that contain some constant parameter, I want to draw that function, on say same figure, using hold on (probably) while changing the value of that constant.
This my code:

```
close all
clear all
clc
m = 5;
x = 1:1:10;
y = m*x + 10;
h1 = figure;
plot(x,y)
m = 10;
figure(h1);
hold on
plot(x,y,': r')
```

When I tried using this code, I got two lines coincident on each others; and it looks matlab just used last value for the parameter `m` how can I make it use different values.
I found some stuff [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16722010/matlab-plot-a-function-with-different-parameters-into), but doesn't fulfill my needs.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to recalculate `y` as well:

```
m = 5;
x = 1:1:10;
y = m*x + 10;

h1 = figure;
plot(x,y); hold on;

m = 10;
y = m*x + 10;

figure(h1);
plot(x,y,': r')
```

Or create an anonymous function:

```
x = 1:1:10;
f = @(m) m*x + 10;

%// and then:
h1 = figure;
plot(x,f(5)       ); hold on;
plot(x,f(10),': r');
```

Comment: all fine, however, in my actual situation, I want use that for PID control, where I've my parameters and ODE equations defined in one file (function file), and the parameters values and plots are defined in another m-file (the run file), you may check [this](http://http://www.google.com.sa/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstaff.kfupm.edu.sa%2FSE%2Fmshahab%2F081_ee656_hw5_sol_shahab.pdf&ei=DxVsVbCzFILbU-7hgIAF&usg=AFQjCNFeTZTAKkzjwgHv8F4XhUwvPZKIPQ) for two links robot. Or should  I post a new question? many thanks.

Comment: @AlFagera I cant open the link, but I'd guess it's definetely a new question.

Comment: @ thewaywewalk, Sorry for that; [this] (http://staff.kfupm.edu.sa/SE/mshahab/081_ee656_hw5_sol_shahab.pdf) , is the correct link.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you're only updating `m` but you also have to calculate `y` again. This is why it plots exactly the same y (i.e. m is still 5) function when you issue the second plot.

You might want to use a simple for loop for that, like:

```
m = 5;
x = 1:1:10;
figure;
hold on;
for m=1:1:10
    y = m*x + 10;
    plot(x,y,': r')
end
```

Comment: if I want to make `legend` in this case using `for` loop, how it'll work.

Comment: .. see my other answer.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the [short](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30558020/how-to-plot-a-matlab-function-for-different-parameters-using-hold-on-command/30558140#30558140) answer - improving the `plot`..

```
    %% Data Preparations
    x = 1:10;
    ms = 3;             % number of different slopes

    %% Graph Preparations
    hold on;

    % Prepare the string cell array
    s = cell(1, ms);

    % Handle storage
    h = zeros(1, ms);

    % Plot graphs
    for m=1:ms
        y = m*x + 10;
        h(m)= plot(x,y,'Color',[1/m rand() rand()]);
        s{m} = sprintf('Plot of y(m=%d)', m);
    end

    % Plot all or select the plots to include in the legend
    ind = [ms:-1:1] .* ones(1,ms);  % plot all
    %ind = [ 1 3 4 ];               % plot selected

    % Create legend for the selected plots
    legend(h(ind), s{ind});
```

Additional advice: When working with MATLAB and you try to improve the performance of your code, you shoud try to avoid using for-loops since MATLAB is MATrix manipulation and that's what it can do best. Ones you've taken this philosophy in, you'll create the most beautiful code one-liners! ;)

---

This script is an adoption of [Steve Lord](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/146397)'s post.